# Como obter uma lista dos valores comuns a duas listas com LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho duas List,

a primeira, que é uma lista que contém todos os estabelecimentos disponíveis na empresa, por exemplo:

---

```
Estabelecimento 

Sigla - XPTO
Descricao - XPTO List
```

```
Estabelecimento 

Sigla - RPTO
Descricao - RPTO List
```

```
Estabelecimento 

Sigla - GTOR
Descricao - GTOR List
```

---

A segunda possuí os estabelecimentos que eu posso ter acesso, que neste caso é apenas :

---

```
Estabelecimento 

Sigla - XPTO
Descricao - XPTO List
```

---

Preciso manter na primeira list apenas os estabelecimentos que eu possuo na segunda.

Return da primeira lista seria :

---

```
Estabelecimento 

Sigla - XPTO
Descricao - XPTO List
```

---

Seria a comparação da primeira com a segunda, removendo da primeiro o que eu não tenho na segunda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julgo que o que pretende é a intercessão entre as duas listas

Use o método [Intersect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx). Ele retorna um IEnumerable com os elementos que existem simultâneamente em ambas as listas

```
lista1 = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```

A classe Estabelecimento deve prover a sua implementação dos métodos `GetHashCode()` e `Equals()`.

Ou use um "comparador de Estabelecimentos" que implemente a interface  `IEqualityComparer<T>`

```
lista1 = list1.Intersect(list2, new EstabelecimentosComparador()).ToList();
```

Comment: Mas ele permite que eu filtre esses elementos e considere na primeira lista apenas o que eu tenho na segunda?

Comment: Após executar o código da resposta a lista1 terá apenas o elementos que existem simultâneamente nas duas listas

Comment: Não tem nenhuma forma de eu efetuar a intercessão sem que eu tenha que implementar a interface IEqualityComparer?

Comment: Usando este método tem de implementar. Mas, mesmo que use outra forma terá sempre de arranjar um modo para saber quando dois objectos Estabelecimento são iguais.

Answer (score 0):

Se são duas listas com o mesmo tipo de objeto, não seria só você atribuir a `lista2` à `lista1` não?

```
todosEstabelecimentos = estabelecimentosComAcesso;
```

Comment: Preciso remover o que não vou utilizar na primeira lista.

Comment: No caso, tenho na segunda lista? Não, então remove, só mostra o que eu tenho na segunda.